# Creating OData Controllers via Reflection with ASPNET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to use ASPNET Core's new ODATA feature to expose data from my application.  All of my data access is exposed through a set of common base classes so instead of creating 50 different ODataController classes, I'd like to have one common class and just instantiate it with different type parameters.  I have my common class created but I am at a loss as to how to tell ASPNETCORE to create a bunch of controllers using reflection.

Does anyone have any examples of how to do this?  I basically want to be able to write code like:

```
ODataControllers.Add(new CommonApiController<MatterJson, IMatterCommand, MatterStorage, MatterApi>());
```

(Of course I'll automate that via reflection as well, I just want to give that as an example).

I have my controller class as follows:

```
public class CommonApiController<TJson, TAdd1, TStorage, TApi> : ODataController
    where TJson : class, IDResult, ITimestamped, new()
    where TAdd1 : class, IApiCommand
    where TStorage : RepositoryItem<TJson, TStorage>, new()
    where TApi : CrudApi<TJson, TAdd1> {

    public ICachedCrudApi<TJson, TAdd1, TStorage, TApi> API { get; private set; }

    public CommonApiController(ICachedCrudApi<TJson, TAdd1, TStorage, TApi> API) {
        this.API = API;
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<TJson> Get(ODataQueryOptions<TJson> options) {
        var settings = new ODataValidationSettings() {
            AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All
        };
        options.Validate(settings);

        var query = API.List().AsQueryable();

        var results = options.ApplyTo(query);
        return (results as IQueryable<TJson>).ToList();
    }


    public virtual async Task<TJson> Get([FromODataUri] long key) {
        var query = await API.Get(key)
            .DefaultAwait()
            ;

        return query.Response;
    }

}
```